# Ruby - Addressing booleans, if/then statements, refute/assert methods, is my code too basic?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, boolean

## TDD

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.2'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/pride'
require './tire'

class TireTest < Minitest::Test


 def test_the_tire_does_not_start_out_flat
  tire = Tire.new
  refute tire.flat?, "This tire is brand new"
 end

 def test_the_tire_has_a_blowout

  tire = Tire.new
  tire.blow_out
  assert tire.flat?, "I ran over a nail!"
 end
end
```

## CODE

```
class Tire
 attr_reader :tire

 def initialize
  @tire = false
 end

 def flat?
  @tire
 end

 def blow_out
  @tire = true
 end
end
```

Better way to solve for this test than what I have? While the simpler you can break down a code and have it make sense to anyone else reading it.

Comment: What is your question? What do you mean by too basic?

Comment: Is there a better way to solve these tests than the code I have written or is a different way someone else would approach this?

Comment: To answer the second part of question you should provide a description of the problem you are trying to solve. For the first part of question your code is generally good enough to pass the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor changes you can apply to your existing solution.

1. `@flat` would be more appropriate name for an attribute since it is itself an attribute of a tire.
2. Encapsulate `attr_reader` unless you need a concrete case of its public usage.
3. Prefer using `attr_reader` over directly calling instance variables.

```
class Tire
  def initialize
    @flat = false
  end

  def flat?
    flat
  end

  def blow_out
    @flat = true
  end

  private

  attr_reader :flat
end
```

Comment: nice, thanks. that makes sense. What is the private for?

Comment: Private is to encaspulate attr_reader. We want only Tire class to have an access to `@flat`.